# Chart.js Library Error While Following YouTube Tutorial

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently following a tutorial on YouTube to create an expense tracker application. When I follow the tutorial exactly as shown on YouTube, I encounter an issue. Instead of working as expected, I receive the following error message: ``your text`Uncaught TypeError: _chart.Chart is undefined <anonymous> Chart.js:20.`

here the `Chart.js` code:

```
import React from 'react'
import useGlobalContext from '../../context/globalContext'
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2'
import { dateFormat } from '../../utils/dateFormat'
import { styled } from 'styled-components'

import {
    Chart as ChartJs,
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    ArcElement,
} from 'chart.js'


ChartJs.register(
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    ArcElement,
)

const Chart = () => {
    const { incomes, expenses } = useGlobalContext()

    const data = {
        labels: incomes.map((inc) => {
            const {date} = inc
            return dateFormat(date)
        }),
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Income",
                data: [
                    ...incomes.map((income) => {
                        const {amount} = income
                        return amount
                    })
                ],
                backgroundColor: 'green',
                tension: .2
            },
            {
                label: "Expense",
                data: [
                    ...expenses.map((expense) => {
                        const {amount} = expense
                        return amount
                    })
                ],
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                tension: .2
            }
        ]
    }

    return (
        <ChartStyled>
            <Line data={data} />
        </ChartStyled>
    )
}

const ChartStyled = styled.div`
    background: #FCF6F9;
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 100%;
`

export default Chart
```

"Did I make a mistake? Please help, masters."

Comment: sounds like an error while importing ... you may want to put the `import {} from 'chart.js'` above the `import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2'`

Comment: But why does what's shown in the video work successfully?

Comment: its wont rendered on web browser

Comment: it's very hard to say as we firtstly don't know of which video you are talking and secondly don't now if you have installed all packages (`npm install`)

Comment: I have installed all the dependencies.

Comment: it would be good if you use lower case `c` for you `const Chart` and `export default Chart` so that they don't collide with the `Chart` from chart.js

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the appropriate version of the Chart.js library that supports the api you are using in your code. If you use a mismatched version, it could also cause problems

Comment: try to match it with the tutorial video you followed
or try upgrade/downgrde the version